# Track how many time device was unlocked?

Tags: java, android

Im just curious is there any way to track how many time user unclocked its phone , and also get duration of time it spents on that particluar session ?

Answer (score 0):

On Andorid, `UsageStatsManager` class provides access to device usage history and statistics. Usage data is aggregated into time intervals: days, weeks, months, and years.

```
UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeSince = currentTime - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Look back 24 hours

List<UsageStats> stats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, timeSince, currentTime);
int unlockCount = 0;
long sessionDuration = 0;

for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
   unlockCount += usageStats.mLaunchCount;
   sessionDuration += usageStats.mTotalTimeInForeground;
}

Log.d("Unlock Count", "Number of unlocks: " + unlockCount);
Log.d("Session Duration", "Total session duration in milliseconds: " + sessionDuration);
```